# Possible to add a description to a dropdown?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to ask if it is possible to create a dropdown like the following image:

[image]

The client would love for it to be like that however I checked on some of the ways and I have not found a way that works.

Comment: what if each dropdown option could display a `tooltip` on hover?

Comment: I thought as well for that, but was wondering if what am trying is possible. I will go with the tooltip option if not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

HI Kaygee Del Hlobo,

It is not possible to modify the internal content of the dropdown in this way with pure HTML and CSS, since the rendering of the dropdown menu `select` is controlled by the operating system and the browser, and does not allow custom HTML within the options.

The best way to achieve what you want is to create a custom dropdown.

```html
<style>
  .dropdown-container {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  .dropdown-btn {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
  .dropdown-content p {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #666;
  }
  .dropdown-option {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dropdown-option:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  .dropdown-option:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .show { display: block; }
</style>

<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="dropdown-btn" onclick="toggleDropdown()">Business Size</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown">
    <p>This includes your staff, contract and temporary staff for your organization, business, NPO, NGO, and more.</p>
    <div class="dropdown-option" onclick="setBusinessSize('Micro (1-10)')">Micro (1-10)</div>
    <div class="dropdown-option" onclick="setBusinessSize('Small (11-50)')">Small (11-50)</div>
    <div class="dropdown-option" onclick="setBusinessSize('Medium (51-250)')">Medium (51-250)</div>
    <div class="dropdown-option" onclick="setBusinessSize('Large (251 - more)')">Large (251 - more)</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
function toggleDropdown() {
  var dropdownContent = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdown-btn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.style.display === "block") {
        openDropdown.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

function setBusinessSize(size) {
  var dropdownBtn = document.querySelector('.dropdown-btn');
  dropdownBtn.textContent = size;
  toggleDropdown();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. IT is exactly what I am looking for. I will make a few CSS changes but its exactly what I need. Appreciate it.

Comment: is it possible to have the icon show? It is currently not showing.